# How to refresh Oracle Materialized view using sqlalchemy - Python

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

How to execute Oracle Materialize view using `sqlalchemy`?

```py
mview = 'mv_test'          
mview_refresh_sql = f"EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('{mview}', method => '?')"

try:          
  conn.execute(mview_refresh_sql)         
Exception as err:           
  print({err})
```

It is throwing error: `Error in refreshing MVIEW mv_covid19_jhu_trend : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

Comment: The refresh method: F-Fast, P-Fast_PCT, ?-Force, C-Complete

Answer (score 0):

just figured out... works with below changes

mview_refresh_sql = f"BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('{mview}', method => '?');  END;"